# Can SQL Reporting Services generate reports automatically?

Tags: 2007, reporting-services, reports

I need to set up a report generation system for a SharePoint list.  The report will display all items within the date range that is specified by the user with a start and end date.  The requirement for this is that the user must just enter a start and end date (preferably with a date picker) and have a report gereated for them automatically.

Can SQL Reporting Services be set up to generate a report automatically with just a minimum of entering a start and end date from the user?

I have not set up SQL Reporting Services yet so I cannot test this myself.  If SQL Reporting Services cannot do this or if there is an easier way, please advise.  The server is SharePoint 2007 Standard, not Enterprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can.

You can set up scheduled reports that users are subscribed to.  They can be delivered by email, dropped in a folder, or stored in SSRS (for retrieval manually via the SSRS web site).

You can have data driven reports.  This allows you to have a database table with 100 records, and each record can specify the parameters for the report and the email address of the user to send the report to.

Or you can have a simpler scheduled report where a user goes in and subscribes to one manually.

For more information, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762.aspx

Comment: I would add -- the free (express) version of SSRS does not have the scheduling capability.